# Prove that $\omega(n) \ll \frac{ \log n} {\log \log n}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

> Let $\omega(n)$ the number of distinct prime divisors of an integer
> n, so for instance $\omega(12) = 2$. Show that $\omega(n) \ll \frac{ \log n} {\log \log n}$.

This question is from assignment 2 of this course:[http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015.html](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html)

I am self studying this course. This will involve things studied in 4th lecture.

Well results available are that for almost all n,$\omega(n)= \log \log n(1+o(1))$ and 1 result that there always exists a density 1 subsequence {$n_j$} of positive integers such that $\omega(n_j) =\log \log(n_j) (1+o(1) ) $ as j tends to $\infty$ and theorem of Turan that  $\sum_{n\leq x} (\omega(n) - \log \log x)^2 =O( x\log \log x)$

I tried using the subsequence result but I am not even close to what has been asked.

So, please tell how should I prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another trick is by partitioning $\omega(n)$ into two parts:

$$
\omega(n)=\sum_{\substack{p|n\\p\le t}}1+\omega(n,t)
$$

where $\omega(n,t)$ here denotes the number of prime divisors of $n$ that are greater than $t$. By the property of factorization, we know trivially that $t^{\omega(n,t)}<n$, so we have

$$
\omega(n)<\pi(t)+{\log n\over\log t}
$$

Now, apply Chebyshev's estimate we obtain

$$
\omega(n)\ll{t\over\log t}+{\log n\over\log t}
$$

Finally, setting $t=\log n$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Can you please tell how to deduce $t^{\omega(n,t)} <n$ . Sorry , I am asking this late but I was really busy in past months.

Comment: Let $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{\omega(n,t)}$ be the prime factors of $n$ greater than $t$, then we have $n\ge p_1p_2\dots p_{\omega(n,t)}\ge t^{\omega(n,t)}$.

Comment: I must say you are very helpful and due to personal reasons I couldn't accept  your answers earlier. I am really sorry for that. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are an asset to this site.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\omega(n)=k$, and write
$$n=q_1^{e_1}\cdots q_k^{e_k}$$
with $e_1,\dots,e_k\geq 1$ and $q_1<q_2<\cdots<q_k$ prime. Then
$$n\geq (1)(2)\cdots(k)=k!.$$
We find
$$\frac{\log k!}{\log\log k!}\geq \frac{\log\left((k/2)^{k/2}\right)}{\log\log k^k}\geq \frac{\frac k2\log(k/2)}{\log k+\log\log k}\geq \frac{k}{8}.$$
This means that, for large enough $n$,
$$\omega(n)=k\leq \frac{8\log k!}{\log \log k!}\leq \frac{8\log n}{\log\log n}.$$

Comment: Hi!, how you wrote $log k! \geq log ((k/2)^{k/2})$ in the 1st 2 ineqalities $\frac{\log k!}{\log\log k!}\geq \frac{\log\left((k/2)^{k/2}\right)}{\log\log k^k}\geq \frac{\frac k2\log(k/2)}{\log k+\log\log k}\geq \frac{k}{8}.$and how in 3rd and 4th inequalities you wrote $\frac{log(k/2) }{ log k +log log k}\geq 1/4$? Kindly tell.

Comment: @James This is because
$$\frac{\log(k/2)}{\log k+\log\log k}\geq \frac{\log k-\log 2}{2\log k}\geq \frac12-\frac{\log 2}{2\log k}\geq \frac 14,$$
at least for large $k$. The bounding is rather crude here; all that's important is that
$$\frac{\log(k/2)}{\log k+\log\log k}$$
is lower-bounded by some constant for $k$ large.

Comment: I asked 2 questions in comment but you answered only 2nd. Kindly help with 1st also.

Comment: Note that k could be 1 also as k=$\omega (n)$ and then your argument will fail. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Let $d(n)$ denote the number of positive divisors of $n$. Then we know that $\omega(n)\le\log d(n)/\log2$, with equality iff $n$ is squarefree. Now, it suffices to show that

$$
\log d(n)\ll{\log n\over\log\log n}
$$

In this answer, we are going to prove an even stronger result that

**Proposition:** The maximal order of $\log d(n)$ is $\log2\log n/\log\log n$. That is
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}{\log d(n)\log\log n\over\log2\log n}=1\tag1
$$

*Proof.* By the multiplicative property of $d(n)$, we know that

$$
d(n)=\prod_{p^k\|n}(k+1)=\prod_{p^k\|n,p\le t}(k+1)\prod_{p^k\|n,p>t}(k+1)\tag2
$$

where the parameter $t>0$ will be chosen later. Because $p^k\|n$ indicates that $k\le\log n/\log2$ with equality iff $p=2$, we can bound the first product by

$$
\prod_{p^k\|n,p\le t}(k+1)\le\left(1+{\log n\over\log2}\right)^t\tag3
$$

For the second product, we can apply $k+1\le2^k$ to get

$$
\prod_{p^k\|n,p>t}(k+1)\le\prod_{p^k\|n,p>t}2^k\tag4
$$

To continue, we apply Rankin's trick on $p>t$. Since $\log p/\log t>1$ iff $p>1$, we plug this into (4) to get

$$
\prod_{p^k\|n,p>t}(k+1)\le\prod_{p^k\|n}2^{k\log p/\log t}=\left(\prod_{p\|n}p^k\right)^{\log2/\log t}=\exp\left(\log2\log n\over\log t\right)\tag5
$$

Now, plugging (3) and (5) into (2), we have

\begin{aligned}
\log d(n)
&\le t\log\left(1+{\log n\over\log2}\right)+{\log2\log n\over\log t} \\
&\le{\log2\log n\over\log t}+\mathcal O(t\log\log n)
\end{aligned}

For convenience, we wish to set $t=u\log n$ so that

$$
\log d(n)\le{\log2\log n\over\log\log n+\log u}+\mathcal O(u\log n\log\log n)\tag6
$$

To ensure that the O term does not assimilate the main term, we set $u=(\log\log n)^{-3}$ so that

$$
\log d(n)\le{\log2\log n\over\log\log n}\left[1+\mathcal O\left(\log\log\log n\over\log\log n\right)\right]\tag7
$$

This indicates that the limit in (1) is $\le1$. To establish equality, it suffices to find a sequence $n_k$ such that $\log d(n_k)\sim{\log2\log n_k/\log\log n_k}$ as $k\to+\infty$. Indeed, if we let $n_k$ be the product of first $k$ primes then $d(n)=2^k$. Then we have

$$
\log n_k=\sum_{p\le p_k}\log p=\vartheta(p_k)\tag8
$$

Since Chebyshev's theorem asserts $c_1x\le\vartheta(x)\le c_2x$ for some absolute $c_2>c_1>0$, we take logarithm on (8) to obtain

$$
\log\log n_k=\log p_k+\mathcal O(1)\tag9
$$

Moreover, because $\vartheta(x)\le\pi(x)\log x$, we have $\log n_k\le k\log p_k$. This, together with (9), implies

$$
\begin{aligned}
k
&={k\log p_k\over\log p_k}\ge{\log n_k\over\log p_k} \\
&={\log n_k\over\log\log n_k+\mathcal O(1)} \\
&={\log n_k\over\log\log n_k}\left[1+\mathcal O\left(1\over\log\log n\right)\right]
\end{aligned}\tag{10}
$$

Combining (10) and (7), we deduce (1).